# How to get rid off of the 0x?

Tags: python, int, hex

I have the next string 0x00x41 is an hexadecimal code but I want to get rid off of the 0x. Can you tell someone how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it with this:

```
x = 0x00x41
y = x.replace("0x", "")
print (y)
```

The output should be:

```
041
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows, note that the `1` as argument for `replace` makes it such that only the first occurance of the string is replaced:

```
s = '0x00x41'
new_s = s.replace("0x", "", 1)

print(new_s)
```

Giving the following result:

```
00x41
```